# Indexed placeholders in MySql using python mysql.connector module

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

How to use Indexed placeholders in MySQL using python?
There is the following program below.

```
match = [(name1,address1),(name2,address2),(name3,address3),(name4,address4)]

sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO customers (address) VALUES(Only_second_values_from_tuples_of_match)"
mycursor.executemany(sqlQuery,match)
mydb.commit()
```

I want to add addresses in the address column of table 'customers'. Is there any way that the sqlQuery access only second values from tuples of match list? What type of placeholders should I use?

Comment: ALTER TABLE is not use to modify the values of your rows (you should use UPDATE). ALTER TABLE is used to modify the table characteristics. So your query is wrong

Comment: Kindly see the problem again. Thank you for the correction. I probably mad that mistake in hurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use list comprehension to make a tuple with the values you need:

```
match = [(name1,address1),(name2,address2),(name3,address3),(name4,address4)]
tup = tuple([element[1] for element in match])
sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO customers (address) VALUES (%s)"
mycursor.executemany(sqlQuery,tup)
mydb.commit()
```

What you get in `tup` is a tuple with just the second elements of your list, something like this:

```
tup=(address1, address2, address3, address4)
```

Of course, I suppose that name1, address1, name2, address2, etc are variables, because if the are not you need to use `''`.